# When create a controller show an msg

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create MVC 5 controller using scaffolding on EF entity as model and I get this error:

> 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'TSystem.Models.YSummary'. One or
>   more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   TSystem.Service.YSummary:EntityType 'YSummary' has no key defined.
>   Define the key for this EntityType. YSummaryDBSet : EntityType: Entity
>   Set 'YSummaryDBSet' is based on type 'YSummary' that has no keys
>   defined.

Comment: This is not a bad question. Only asked with a little rusty English. People should not vote it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is somewhat clear. You have an EF entity called `YSummary` which has no primary key.

- If you are using code first add an Id property to the class and
  migrate.
- If you are using database first add primary key field in the
  table and regenerate the model
- If you are using model first do like
  code first but in the model

Comment: Actually that is not a table (database), but a view (selected table view in SQL) .... is that EF entity difficult to treat VIEW?

Comment: I didn't know you can use views as source for entities! But if you are doing that then certainly you can assign a primary key to your view. It's non standard though and hard to maintain. Try having an entity for each table. If that's hard to work create a data access layer that transforms data to new objects.